# How do I only allow one iframe and disallow iframe into another iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

On a page let's say `test.html` the following code is generating iframe's

```
<iframe src='" + localStorage.getItem(z) + "' class='alink'></iframe>
```

The links in the iframes are defined as `/product-1` `/product-2`. Now due to the shopping cart settings. The following happens.

The user comes on `site/test.html`

one iframe loads the url `site/product-1`

the other iframe loads the url `site/product-2`

products are now both added to the shopping cart but the shopping cart redirects automatically back to `test.html` which then again loads the iframes and add the products to the cart. So this is a Loop which adds a bit too many products to the cart ;-)

I can't change the redirect behavior as it would mess up the way customers are used to working with the site. So I was thinking there must be a way to iframe's nestings.

So how do I only allow one iframe and disallow iframe into another iframe.

```
    // RETRIEVER

    (function ($) {
      $(document).ready(function(){
        let dummy = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(v => v.startsWith("LinkOrderURL"));
        dummy.forEach(z => $("body").append("<iframe src='" + localStorage.getItem(z) + "' class='alink'></iframe>"));
      });
    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I used this code to encapsulate the above and that made it work.

```
if ( self !== top ) {
  // you're in an iframe
} else {
  // you're not in an iframe
}
```